# Finding Effects of a Treatment

Tags: r, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to find the effects of a treatment on smoking using R. On one day, a person receives a treatment (indicated by "1" in the treatment column). I want to get the weekly sums of how many cigarettes they smoke per day (column "cigarettes") for the two weeks before and after the treatment (Day 22). Here is the dput of my table. (I'm sorry that it's fairly long.)

```
structure(list(person = c("Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", 
"Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", 
"Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", 
"Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", 
"Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", 
"Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", 
"Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy", "Cindy"), year = c("2022", 
"2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", 
"2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", 
"2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", 
"2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", 
"2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", 
"2022", "2022", "2022"), day = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
"17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", 
"28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", 
"39", "40", "41", "42", "43"), cigarettes = c("12", "5", "7", 
"7", "4", "6", "8", "5", "6", "3", "5", "2", "7", "8", "4", "4", 
"10", "4", "8", "1", "8", "7", "5", "4", "2", "9", "4", "2", 
"0", "5", "1", "0", "5", "0", "0", "3", "3", "1", "3", "2", "4", 
"0", "3", "0"), treatment = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0")), row.names = 2:45, class = "data.frame")
```

I'd like to place the weekly results in a separate dataframe. Here's an image and the dput of what I'm trying to do.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Hrlr.png)

```
structure(list(person = "Cindy", year = 2022L, day = 22L, x.2 = 35L, 
    x.1 = 42L, x = 5L, x1 = 26L, x2 = 12L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
)
```

In the output dataframe, I'm trying to include the person, year, and day of the treatment. Column x.2 is the sum of cigarettes smoked in the second week prior to the treatment (day 8:14); x.1 is the sum of cigarettes smoked one week before treatment (15:21); x is the amount of cigarettes smoked the day of treatment; x1 is one week after (23:29); and x2 is the sum for week 2 (30:36).

Here's my current code:df = cigarettes_data

```
# Create a new variable to represent the weeks relative to the treatment day
cigarettes_data <- cigarettes_data %>%
mutate(week = ifelse(day < 22, floor((day - 8)/7) + 1, floor((day - 22)/7) + 1))

# Summarize the data for each week
summary_cigarettes <- cigarettes_data %>%
group_by(person, year, week) %>%
summarize(cigarettes_sum = sum(as.numeric(cigarettes)))
```

As you can probably tell, there are a lot of problems with it. For example, I'm going to have a lot of treatments that occur on different days, so I can't just represent the treatment with Day 22. Also, when I try to create a "week" column, the week numbers ascend (e.g., 0, 1, 2, 3...) instead of originate from the treatment row (e.g., -2, -1, x, 1, 2). Additionally, I'd like to cap the output at two weeks on either side of the treatment day (I don't need the sums of the third weeks and above). I was thinking about something like the following code, but I'm not completely sure how to do it:

```
res <- c()
for (i in idx) {
  trt <- cigarette_data$cigarettes
  x.2 <- trt[(i-2)]
  x.1 <- trt[(i-1)]
  x <- trt[i]
  x1 <- trt[(i+1)]
  x2 <- trt[(i+2)]
  res <- rbind(res,c(x.2, x.1, x, x1, x2))
}
```

Lastly, the current code drops the intervention day column, and I'd ideally like to keep it to identify different interventions for the same person in the same year.

Feel free to ask if you need anything to be clarified.

Comment: If you already have the data your question is not about `experimental-design`

Comment: That's a good point. Thanks! I'll change the tag.